# Refresh data live with fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have fullCalendar that displays events that can be edited by different users and calendar is refetching events every 15sec with this function:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
},  15* 1000);
```

But when status of event is changed I cant see live updates (color change, popup alert etc.) but everything works when page is refreshed manually or when event is created inside 30min of its beginning.

Full code for eventRender is there:

```
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

                if (view.name == 'agendaDay') {
                    $('.fc-event-title').css("display", "block"); 
                }
                var mili = event.start.getTime() - now.getTime();
                var hour = now.getTime();
                var eventhour= event.start.getTime();
                if(event.status == 'open') {
                    if (eventhour< hour) {
                        element.css('background-color', '#999');
                    }
                    else{
                        element.css('background-color', '#70D549');
                        }
                    }
                else if(event.status == 'done') {
                    element.css('background-color', '#B2F0FF');
                    }
                else if(event.status == 'invalid') {
                    element.css('background-color', '#CC0000');
                    }
                else if(event.status == 'booked') {
                    if(mili < 1800000 && mili > 0){ 
                        $(".name2").html(event.status);
                        $(".t2").html(event.btitle);
                        $(".n2").html(event.name);
                        $(".s2").html(event.surname);
                        $(".ad2").html(event.address);
                        $(".zp2").html(event.city);
                        $(".ct2").html(event.zip);
                        $(".tl2").html("Tel: "+event.tel);
                        $(".ml2").html(event.email);
                        $(".title2").html('<strong>Description:</strong><br/>'+event.title+'');
                        var hcs1 = event.start.getHours();
                        var hcs = ("0" + hcs1).slice(-2);
                        var mcs1 = event.start.getMinutes();
                        var mcs = ("0" + mcs1).slice(-2);
                        $(".start2").html(hcs + ':' +mcs);
                        var hce1 = event.end.getHours();
                        var hce = ("0" + hce1).slice(-2);
                        var mce1 = event.end.getMinutes();
                        var mce = ("0" + mce1).slice(-2);
                        $(".end2").html(hce + ':' + mce);
                        var dc1 = event.start.getDate();
                        var dc = ("0" + dc1).slice(-2);
                        var mc1 = event.start.getMonth()+1;
                        var mc = ("0" + mc1).slice(-2);
                        var yc = event.start.getFullYear();
                    $(".date").html(dc + '.' + mc + '.' + yc + '.');
                        element.css('background-color','#00CCFF');
                        if(!localStorage[event.id+"alertdisplayed"]) {
                        $('.alert').dialog({ 
                            buttons: [{ 
                            text: "OK", 
                                click: function() { 
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                        localStorage[event.id+"alertdisplayed"] = true
                        }
                    }

                    if (eventhour < hour) {
                        element.css('background-color', '#B2F0FF');
                    }
                    else{
                        element.css('background-color', '#00CCFF');
                        }
                    }
                else if(event.status == 'storn') {
                    element.css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refetch events on a change:

```
$("#someID").change(function () {
    $('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});
```

Not as nice, but should work is to do it this way:

```
$('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', source )
$('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source )
```

Comment: It has to be time interval so I can't use `.change`. I tried removing and adding event source but it doesnt work also.